# Orchard null reference error when add a new term for and taxonomy

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

We are using Orchard 1.8.1 and when add a new term for a taxonomy we get this error. We didn't change anything in codes.

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Source Error:

```
Line 3:  @using Orchard.Fields.Settings;
Line 4:  @{
Line 5:      var settings = Model.PartFieldDefinition.Settings.GetModel<BooleanFieldSettings>();
Line 6:  }
Line 7:  <fieldset>
```

Source File: `c:\Websites\--\Modules\Orchard.Fields\Views\EditorTemplates\Fields\Boolean.Edit.cshtml    Line: 5`

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Orchard.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.FieldIdFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\Mvc\Html\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs:32
   ASP._Page_Modules_Orchard_Fields_Views_EditorTemplates_Fields_Boolean_Edit_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Websites\--\Modules\Orchard.Fields\Views\EditorTemplates\Fields\Boolean.Edit.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +124
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName) +98
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.RenderInternal(HtmlHelper Html, TextWriter Output, String TemplateName, Object Model, String Prefix) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:755
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.EditorTemplate(HtmlHelper Html, TextWriter Output, String TemplateName, Object Model, String Prefix) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:743

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +193
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.PerformInvoke(DisplayContext displayContext, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object serviceInstance) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:64
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateDelegate>b__3(DisplayContext context) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:55
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name, INamedEnumerable`1 parameters) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:44
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:29
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.ContentZone(Object Display, Object Shape, TextWriter Output) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:274

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +193
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.PerformInvoke(DisplayContext displayContext, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object serviceInstance) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:64
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateDelegate>b__3(DisplayContext context) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:55
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name, INamedEnumerable`1 parameters) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:44
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:29
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   ASP._Page_Core_Contents_Views_Content_Edit_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Websites\--\Core\Contents\Views\Content.Edit.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +125
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +147
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:151
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:133
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name, INamedEnumerable`1 parameters) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:44
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:29
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   ASP._Page_Modules_Orchard_Taxonomies_Views_TermAdmin_Create_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Websites\--\Modules\Orchard.Taxonomies\Views\TermAdmin\Create.cshtml:6
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +125
   Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.<>c__DisplayClass7.<FindView>b__5(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:59
   Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.LayoutView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:90
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +380
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +109
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in e:\orchard\source\Orchard.Source.1.8.1\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:159
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: What were your steps to come to this? It looks like you added a booleanfield to the taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we set the term name in Farsi and Orchard renamed (truncated) it without warning.